# dynamically changing button theme

Tags: java, android, android-button

I have two styles for my button:

```
<style name="PrimaryButton1" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/blackt</item>
</style>
<style name="PrimaryButton2" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I know i can set a theme in my layout xml like this:
`<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton1"/>`

but i want to change the theme between these two styles when a click event occur.
(the reason i am using themes is changing the background of my button makes it's reveal effect delete)
how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Add an *id* for the Button **Or** Add the `android:onClick="{method name}"` to the Button XML
> 2. Add this code into your Activity / Fragment
>     (Assuming you've defined a variable for the Button named *button*)
>
>    > Inside an
>    >
>    > > Activity: 
>    > >       `button.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.PrimaryButton2);` 
>    > >       Fragment:`button.setTextAppearance(getContext(), R.style.PrimaryButton2);`